# Parsing complex xml tag

Tags: xslt

I have below xml file

```
    <sect2>
      <title>Prophylaxis</title>
      <para><calc type="weight"/> EXAMPLE DATA</para>
      <para>2 months</para>
    </sect2>
```

I tried with some regular expressions, but no luck

I wanted to extract "EXAMPLE DATA" using xslt template.

Comment: This is a trivial task in XSLT. Spend half an hour with a tutorial and you will know how to do it. -- P.S. Do not try using regex to parse XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want XPath to extract data from XML, refer below or [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6N/1):

```
<xsl:value-of select="//sect2/para"/>
```